# JDBC pooling related to ntp sync?

Tags: jdbc, time, connection-pooling, timeout

We're having a connection timeout issue from an API pooling connections to an informix connection manager which forwards the queries to the appropriate informix database server.
Recently, I've set up the mail service and realized that we're having delays in receiving the mail send and after troubleshooting I saw that the database server is not syncronized at all with the API ( 2+ minutes difference ).
I've read somewhere that time sync is important when using jdbc pooling but  I can't find to much information regarding this on internet. The timeout kinda makes sense because of the tcp keepalive.
Had anyone experienced or know about this ?
Thank you,
Mihai.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to intermix database timestamps and local timestamps.   This causes issues when the server times are different.  If the mail server is looking for records before the current time, there could be a two minute delay before mail is sent.

Email may be delayed in transit between servers. Check the Received headers to see if there are any unexpected delays.  (You will need to compensate for time variances on the servers.

Normally, you would use NTP to ensure the time is the same on all servers.  Within a data center it should be able to synchronize times to a millisecond or so.